# Bern-Carrasco-Johansson (BCJ) Double Copy and Color-Kinematic duality

Tags: quantum-gravity, quantum-chromodynamics, duality, grand-unification, color-charge

According to [the wikipedia page on Strong Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_gravity), the theory is considered "non-mainstream", but from what I can gather there have been some [very interesting progress and results](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06963) since it was first proposed by Salam and Sivaram in the late 70s.

One of these seem to be the [BCJ Double copy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0476) and the so-called [Color-Kinematics duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07388), I wanted to ask for some overview of the subject that fits within the expected format of this site, as it seems to be offering a constrasting viewpoint compared to traditional GUT-style unification, in the sense that rather than to try to unify QCD with the electroweak sector, it first unifies gravity with QCD/Yang-Mills as intermediate step.

Comment: The claims of Akinto & Tahir paper are just too extraordinary and raise a few flags: **it turns lead into gold** and **it gives immortality**. Double copy by itself (outside of questionable context above) is a mainstream subject, but it is not a unification per se but rather duality: it relates things (quantum amplitudes, classical solutions) in one theory with  things in the another theory.

Comment: @A.V.S. what in your view would qualify as "unification per se"?

Comment: “my view” is that unification of two theories $T_1$ and $T_2$ is a third theory $T_3$ that contains both $T_1$ & $T_2$ (for example through some sort of limiting procedure(s)).

Comment: @A.V.S. I have the impression that BCJ is actually writing GR metric as some sort of product of two Yang-Mill gauge fields, if that is a valid way to describe BCJ, how would that approach fail to contain either gravity or QCD?

Comment: Perhaps what you meant is that to be proper unification, you need to have more structure that describes how 3 Yang-Mill sectors become a paired couple that becomes long-range gravity and an unpaired one that becomes QCD?

Comment: BCJ deals with quantum amplitudes (as in S-matrix). Writing the metric from YM solutions is what is called *classical double copy*. For an example see [1410.0239](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0239).

Comment: … *you need to have more structure* … May be. *Web of dualities* in string theories is seen as an evidence for a existence of unifying M-theory. But by itself a duality is not a unification (that is not a theory) but a mapping between theories.